# Wildcard in jquery autocomplete field name

Tags: jquery

I need a wildcard for digits that come after my #TagEntry in this jquery selector. I tried the code below and a number of other variations but it does not work. I want it to accept #TagEntry1, #TagEntry2, all the way up to #TagEntry999.

```
//jQuery Auto Complete
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("[#TagEntry*]").autocomplete({source:'FavoriteTagList.php', minLength:1});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('[id^="TagEntry"]')`.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/00hwj2az/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correclty you can use the following, which selects all elements that start with `TagEntry`:

```
$('[id^="TagEntry"]')
```

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/3y2xv4qm/

Good luck!!